# Runtime Permission exception even already granted

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtimeexception

I ran into the very different problem,

In app without granting the `READ_PHONE_STATE` & `SEND_SMS` permission we are not allowed to use the app,

I am taking this permission on the splash screen.

even though the permission is granted and I am trying to fetch the `moTelephoneMgr.getLine1Number()` I am getting runtime exception in the firebase for some **specific device**.

Any way to resolve this issue?

Below is the exception

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver 
app.receivers.SimChangeReceiver: java.lang.SecurityException:     
getLine1NumberForDisplay: Neither user 10275 nor current process has 
[REDACTED_DOMAIN_NAME]_PHONE_STATE or [REDACTED_DOMAIN_NAME]_SMS. 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3098) 
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (ActivityThread.java) 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1588) 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102) 
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154) 
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6247) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java) 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:762) 


Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: getLine1NumberForDisplay: Neither 
user 10275 nor current process has [REDACTED_DOMAIN_NAME]_PHONE_STATE or 
[REDACTED_DOMAIN_NAME]_SMS. 
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1683) 
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1636) 
com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy
.getLine1NumberForDisplay(ITelephony.java:4021) 
android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getLine1Number 
(TelephonyManager.java:2338) 
android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getLine1Number 
(TelephonyManager.java:2315) 
app.receivers.SimChangeReceiver.onReceive (SimChangeReceiver.java:47) 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3091) 
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (ActivityThread.java) 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1588) 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102) 
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154) 
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6247) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java) 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Please look into the manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="app.myPackage">

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/> -->

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<application
    android:name=".AppGlobal"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:manageSpaceActivity=".WelcomeActivity"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TermsConditions"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_registration"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/setting"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Help"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_help"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".About"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <!-- put this somewhere into your application section: -->
    <receiver android:name=".receivers.SimChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

Gradle

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.myPackage"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 95
    versionName '9.7'
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.6'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.6'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.6'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'
 compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.7.0'
 compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Comment: share your manifest file.

Comment: @HemantParmar shared

Comment: its not complete xml, share whole file, i want to check tag.

Comment: @HemantParmar now?

Comment: what is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: @RRR_1173 you can run `checkSelfPermission()` before proceeding to `moTelephoneMgr.getLine1Number()`. It may be the case, user has given permission and revoked it later.